# Ejabberd's external authentication, chats and admin web access

Tags: ejabberd

just two questions about Ejabberd. I saw and adapted PHP tool found through GitHub (https://github.com/leesherwood/ejabberd-php-auth) for external authentication, but I have a doubt: when exploiting external authentication, how Ejabberd links users (who are not stored into Ejabberd database but into an external mySQL database used for Web purposes) with conversations, please?

Second question. I have followed guidelines for setting external authentication. It works like a charm when testing by command line, mocking a command like 00auth:username:servername:password

But, when I try to connect to Ejabberd's administration web platform, I receive an error of connection. Instead, when I use internal authorization, the platform is reachable.

Do you figure out the reason, please?

Answer (score 0):

> how Ejabberd links users (who are not stored into Ejabberd database but into an external mySQL database used for Web purposes) with conversations, please?

How? With their username+hostname.

> when I try to connect to Ejabberd's administration web platform, I receive an error of connection. Instead, when I use internal authorization, the platform is reachable.

Try to login with a Jabber client, does it work? In the WebAdmin, remember to provide the Jabber ID, which is username@hostname, not only the username.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So, if I well understand, Ejabberd conversations do not refer to the user id within the table of users, but directly to the username@hostname, am I correct please?

About the login to the Web administration panel, I try to connect by means of admin@localhost: it works with internal authorization, but doesn't work with external authorization (the admin@localhost user is externally authorized when running the authorization script through command line into ubuntu server)